# Which iOS version should I target fall 2012

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Hi, I've just started working on an iPhone app that I plan to have submitted to the app store the last week of August. Right now I'm using iOS 4.1, but I'm thinking about using iOS 5 since it has support for JSON, what should I do? Use iOS 5 or 4, my app is basically a picture game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

earlier in the year, when i was making a similar decision, i used the data at the [macrumors.com from march](http://www.macrumors.com/2012/03/23/developer-sees-quick-adoption-of-ios-5-1-amongst-users/) to help me determine where my users might be coming from.

the graph at that link shows a pretty steady and very slowly declining share of iOS 4 users.  that is also 4 months old.

also recognize that if you are selling apps, those who are sticking with iOS 4 are likely to be people like my parents, who got an iPad and have never upgraded and don't buy apps, or are too poor to afford an upgrade to a fancier phone, and thus are probably also pinching pennies.

at any rate, rough rule of thumb based on the statistics at that site … you'll probably be giving up on somewhere between 1/6th and 1/10th of the market at this point, and that fraction will be the hardest part of the market to sell to.

you need to decide how aggressive you need to be, how much return you'll get for targeting iOS 4 users based upon how much effort you'll have to put in to be backward compatible, and whether that's worth it.  for me, i built one new app that i made capable of running on iOS 4.2, but another seemed like it would be too much work, so i stuck with iOS 5 .

Comment: How have your apps been doing so far?

Comment: Good answer - providing facts, references _and_ expertise, 3 out of 3 of attributes "we expect answers to be supported by". So why is it closed?

Answer (score 3):

Most people are using iOS 5 now. It's still your decision whether or not to support iOS 4 (obviously, doing so makes your app available to a larger percentage of people; you have to decide if that's worth losing out on iOS 5 specific features).

If JSON is the only deciding factor, there are plenty of iOS 4 compatible JSON libraries like [SBJson](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/).

Answer (score 2):

If nothing stops you from targetting iOS 4, then go for it. You will have more potential customers than if you target iOS 5 only.

Although most people have upgraded to iOS 5, there are still a decent amount of people using iOS 4.

See [these statistics](http://david-smith.org/iosversionstats/) for more information. The link says that they are updated weekly.

Also, make sure to always use the latest SDK (or the beta SDKs if you want). You can target older iOS versions with the latest SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Always use the latest SDK. If you have a developer program membership, you can use the prerelease version, but that is subject to bugs and other issues that you don't want to deal with in a shipping app. So my recommendation is to use the current version of Xcode from the app store, and maybe use the prerelease version to familiarize yourself with upcoming iOS 6 changes and features, but NOT for your main development efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: You are confusing xcode versioning with ios versions. You should probably upgrade to the latest xcode. 4.3.2 i believe? But This is different from ios 4,5,6.

which of those to target was in my original answer.

This is sort of a matter of opinion/how accessible you want your app to be. The lower versions of ios you support the more people will be able to access your app. Thatbeing said, While I dont have a recent breakdown of users across devices,even the iphone 3G can get iOS 5 so you should be pretty safe using it.

Comment: The maximum OS version to support the iPhone 3G is 4.2.1, _not_ iOS 5. The iPhone 3GS will run iOS 5 as well as the upcoming iOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

For new apps I would use iOS 5, at least. If you already are mostly done with the development targeting iOS 4.1, however, I'm not sure it's worth upgrading. Regardless of the iOS version you target you should always use the latest version of Xcode as this will give you better optimisations, more accurate warnings, and a more capable static analyser.